# Google Tag Manager + React App = wrong title

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, helmet.js

I have app writing in React. Last day I implement Google Tag Manager. I create tag, trigger (historyChange). In google anaytics real time I see every change of url but title is wrong.

For example: /url - title

```
/people - People
/video - People
/contact - Video
/people - Contact
```

My title is always step backward.
I use react-helmet for dynamically set head section, title too.

Comment: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-history-listener/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an update lag in React-Helmet. Since Tag Manager is listening to historyChange it fires before the component that includes React-helmet have properly rendered and the title is changing after the page tracking.

A possible solution is to wrap the tag manager in a setTimeout.

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/189